# Spring Boot service layer unit testing with Mockito - mocked data nulled

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito

I'm trying to test service layer using Mockito with JUnit but each time when I run it return object gets nulled.

More info:

- UserRepository is a plain spring data repository extending CRUDRepository.
- User is a plain JPA entity.

and test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UserServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private UserService userService = new UserService();

    private User user;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void tesGetUserIdStatus() {

        // given
        user = new User();
        user.setUserName(userName);
        user.setUserId(userId);

        User newUser = new User();

        // when
        Mockito.when(userRepository.findByUserId(userId)).thenReturn(newUser);
        User result = userService.getUserById(user);

        // then
        Assert.assertEquals(newUser, user);
    }

}
```

That test will end up that expected object values get nulled when actual are correct.

Service part which I want to test looks like:

```
@Component
public class UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
}

    public User getUserById(User user) throws EntityNotFoundException {


        String userId = user.getUserId();

        user = userRepository.findByUserId(userId);

        return user;
    }
...
```

Comment: That is not consistent : `User result = userService.getUser(user);

        // then
        Assert.assertEquals(newUser, user);` You don't assert the returned variable. please post the real/correct code.

Comment: don't use both MockitoRunner and .initMocks - it's almost the same. Also note: your question is not related to SpringBoot

Comment: @davidxxx I have fixed that part of the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see there's a design issue as well in addition to improper user of mockito. The `@InjectMocks` is not a good choice. It's implementation is flawed, here's what their javadocs say.

> - Mockito will try to inject mocks only either by constructor
>     injection,  * setter injection, or property injection in order and as
>     described below.  * If any of the following strategy fail, then
>     Mockito **won't report failure**;  * i.e. you will have
>     to provide dependencies yourself.

I think it should be deprecated so developers could nicely do constructor injection. Have a look at this approach;

Refactor the `UserService` so you could inject the `UserRepository` via `UserService`'s **constructor**.
For example: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html

Then

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UserServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;


    private UserService userService;
    private User user;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
       userService = new UserService(userRepository);
    }

    @Test
    public void tesGetUserIdStatus() {
        //your test code
    }
```

This is good practice and you could test your logic (services, helpers etc) in isolation with right mocks and stubbing.

However, if you want to verify the correct injection of resources by spring ioc container and want to do operations like validation, you should consider proper Spring/Spring boot tests. Have a look at official Spring testing docs -- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html

Comment: Failed on `new UserService(userRepository)` for me

Comment: What's the failure?

Comment: `constructor UserService in class service.UserService cannot be applied to given types`

Comment: "Refactor the UserService so you could inject the UserRepository via UserService's" - any examples of that kind of service with repository injection?

Comment: You will have to show me how you create the `UserService`. There are loads of examples, https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html
https://www.baeldung.com/constructor-injection-in-spring

Comment: I have added more infor

Comment: I have added service code part which I want to test. Re going Spring way to test it I have other tests done that way (full application, repository) but I wasn't able to test service layer standalone so I gave a shot with Mockito which is new to me.

Comment: I have added recommended injection to the service but test still sets values to null. OP is updated with current changes. Thoughts?

Comment: @JackTheKnife why do you call `User result = userService.getUser(user);`? But  In your question the `UserService` shows a different method which is  `getUserById(User user)`. ? So no way that would work.

Comment: Fixed that - still getting `null` on both - result and from Mockito

Comment: Ok, that means given info on the question doesn’t seem to be enough to resolve your issue. Because I have tried my solution and it works fine. You will have to do bit more digging and understand why it’s not working. Perhaps, push your project to Github & share.

Comment: Got it solved before your comment here. Just removed `newUser` which was causing issue on nulled mocked data as well added `this` to `@Before` constructor. Thanks a lot for your help and being patient

Answer (score 1):

By `findByUserId(UserId)` you mean `findByUserId(userId)` and by 
`Assert.assertEquals(newUser, user)` you mean `Assert.assertEquals(result, user)`? And where do the values userName and userId come from?

And please don't use @InjectMocks to inject an UserService

try this instead:

```
@Autowired
private UserService userService;
```

or at least

```
@InjectMock
private UserService userService;
```

Your test may fail because the Repository inside UserService cannot be injected properly and the returned result will be **null**.

Comment: No no `@Autowired` is for autowiring Spring beans. The test class doesn't load any container.

Comment: "Your test may fail because the Repository inside UserService cannot be injected properly and the returned result will be null" - how can I verify that part?

Comment: result == null is a start

Comment: `userName` and `userId` are hardcoded at the beginning of the code. Also I have updated OP with service part which I want to test

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in your test:

- `UserService` is instantiated by Mockito (`@InjectMocks`) - do not initialise it with a new `UserService` instance - that is the reason you are getting NPE
- since you are using `MockitoJUnitRunner` you do not need to explicitly call `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks`
- `when(userRepository.findByUserId(UserId))` - what is `UserId`?
- calling `Mockito.when()` should be a part of the given section
- in the then section you should assert the value you have obtained in the when section

Comment: `userId` in the test is hardcoded. I have updated OP with the service part which I want to test. Side note - I have full app test using `restTemplate` which works fine but can't get service layer tested standalone.